# catch2 run all untagged tests plus hidden ones with specific tags

Tags: c++, catch2

I'm trying to tag all tests that send real network requests with `[.network]` so that they don't run by default. My hope was that I could optionally include them to be ran in addition to all my untagged tests; but I have not been able to figure out how to do this or if it is even possible.

Say I organize my tests like this:

```cpp
TEST_CASE("Foo") { ... }
TEST_CASE("Bar") { ... }
TEST_CASE("Baz", [.optional]) { ... }
TEST_CASE("Qux", [.different-optional]) { ... }
```

When my test exe is run without any additional parameters, I want `Foo` and `Bar` to run. This is working correctly.

However I would like to invoke my test exe such that I can still run all untagged tests, but also include specific tags

E.g.:

- `./tests include:[.optional]` would run `Foo` `Bar` and `Baz`
- `./tests include:[.different-optional]` would run `Foo` `Bar` and `Qux`
- `./tests include:[.optional],include:[.different-optional]` would run `Foo` `Bar` `Baz` and `Qux`

(I know `include:` isn't a keyword, I'm just illustrating the behavior I'm looking for)

Is this possible without having to add some `[all]` or `[default]` tag to all my other tests?

##### Edit:

I had a brief moment of hope, turns out catch2 has support for the empty tag `[]`

So in the example above, running `./tests []` will run `Foo` and `Bar`.

Unfortunately, the empty tag seems to be ignored when combined with the comma `,` separator.

So `./tests [],[.optional]` still only runs `Baz`